# Return all customers that have ordered KFC for two consecutive orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out which customers have made 2 consecutive orders at a restaurant. I'm making use of two tables, Orders and Order_rank.

Order_rank contains a count of a customer’s successful orders - e.g. if an orderid has an order rank of 2 the order in question was the customer’s second consecutive order since their registration.

Orders:

```
Createdate | Orderid  | OrderStatus | Customerid | Restaurantname
---------- | -------  | ----------- | ---------- | --------------
2019-08-03 | 1338     | Accepted    | 45         | KFC            
2019-08-04 | 3266     | Accepted    | 45         | KFC
2019-08-06 | 1595     | Null        | 37         | Burger King 
2019-08-07 | 9258     | Null        | 89         | KFC
2019-08-12 | 4853     | Accepted    | 22         | Burger King
2019-08-13 | 5682     | Null        | 22         | Burger King
2019-08-14 | 3515     | Accepted    | 16         | Burger King
2019-08-16 | 2495     | Accepted    | 16         | KFC
2019-08-22 | 2359     | Accepted    | 35         | KFC
2019-08-25 | 2456     | Null        | 47         | Burger King
```

Order_rank:

```
Customerid | Orderid | Rank
---------- | ------- | ----
16         | 2495    | 2
16         | 3515    | 2 
22         | 4853    | 3
22         | 5682    | 1
35         | 2359    | 1
37         | 1595    | 1
45         | 1338    | 2
45         | 3266    | 2
47         | 2456    | 3
```

The output I want to display is something like this:

```
Customerid | Createdate | Orderid | RestaurantName
---------- | ---------- | ------- | --------------
45         | 2019-08-03 | 1338    | KFC
45         | 2019-08-04 | 3266    | KFC
```

I need to display the order dates of both consecutive orders.

How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried but it didn't work quite how I wanted it to:

```
SELECT

a.Customerid,
a.Createdate,
a.Orderid,
a.Restaurantname

FROM Orders a
INNER JOIN Order_rank b on a.Customerid = b.Customerid

WHERE Rank = 2
AND OrderStatus = 'Accepted'
AND Restaurantname = 'KFC'
```

Comment: Using `LEAD`/`LAG` would be one idea. Gaps and Islands another. What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: what about rank = 3 , you need to display only 2nd and 3rd order details (i.e. last 2 consecutive orders) or all 3 orders ?

Comment: @Larnu I've added the code snippet I tried for review.

Comment: @Suresh Gajera, I only need to show results for 2 consecutive orders, so only where rank = 2

Comment: Try joining with column 'Orderid' as well

Comment: Am I correct in using an INNER JOIN? Could that be my problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of ORDER_RANK table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select o.*   -- whatever columns you want
from (select o.*, orr.customerid,
             lag(o.restaurant) over (partition by o.customerid order by createddate) as prev_restaurant,
             lead(o.restaurant) over (partition by o.customerid order by createddate) as next_restaurant
      from orders o 
     ) o
where restaurant = 'KFC' and
      restaurant in (prev_restaurant, next_restaurant);
```

I don't see any use for `order_rank` in the query, unless you need it for filtering purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I only realized late that order_rank is not needed for my task. the lag and lead functions worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If what you only want is to show orders that has rank 2 in order_rank table, I think, all you need to do is to join the Order table to Order_rank thru Orderid and put a WHERE statement for Rank=2, if you also want to consider ranks that are 3 or more, just change to Rank>=2.

```
SELECT Orders.Customerid,
    Orders.Createdate,
    Orders.Orderid,
   Orders.Restaurantname
FROM Orders LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_rank ON (Orders.Orderid=Order_rank.Orderid)
WHERE Order_rank.Rank=2;
```

Comment: Should I use a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @MgMogaki the joining depends on the db structure or relationship of tables Orders and Orders_rank. Did the code work for you though?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then I would treat this like a Gaps and Islands Problem and do something like this:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
/*
Createdate | Orderid  | OrderStatus | Customerid | Restaurantname
---------- | -------  | ----------- | ---------- | --------------
2019-08-03 | 1338     | Accepted    | 45         | KFC            
2019-08-04 | 3266     | Accepted    | 45         | KFC
2019-08-06 | 1595     | Null        | 37         | Burger King 
2019-08-07 | 9258     | Null        | 89         | KFC
2019-08-12 | 4853     | Accepted    | 22         | Burger King
2019-08-13 | 5682     | Null        | 22         | Burger King
2019-08-14 | 3515     | Accepted    | 16         | Burger King
2019-08-16 | 2495     | Accepted    | 16         | KFC
2019-08-22 | 2359     | Accepted    | 35         | KFC
2019-08-25 | 2456     | Null        | 47         | Burger King
*/
--Sample Data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,V.Createdate) AS Createdate,
           V.Orderid,
           NULLIF(RTRIM(V.OrderStatus),'null') AS OrderStatus,
           V.Customerid,
           RTRIM(V.Restaurantname) AS Restaurantname
    FROM (VALUES('2019-08-03',1338,'Accepted',45,'KFC        '),    
                ('2019-08-04',3266,'Accepted',45,'KFC        '),
                ('2019-08-06',1595,'Null    ',37,'Burger King'), 
                ('2019-08-07',9258,'Null    ',89,'KFC        '),
                ('2019-08-12',4853,'Accepted',22,'Burger King'),
                ('2019-08-13',5682,'Null    ',22,'Burger King'),
                ('2019-08-14',3515,'Accepted',16,'Burger King'),
                ('2019-08-16',2495,'Accepted',16,'KFC        '),
                ('2019-08-22',2359,'Accepted',35,'KFC        '),
                ('2019-08-25',2456,'Null    ',47,'Burger King'))V(Createdate,Orderid,OrderStatus,Customerid,Restaurantname)),
--Solution
Grps AS(
    SELECT V.Createdate,
           V.Orderid,
           V.OrderStatus,
           V.Customerid,
           V.Restaurantname,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.Customerid  ORDER BY V.Orderid) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.Customerid,V.Restaurantname ORDER BY V.Orderid) AS Grp
    FROM VTE V),
Counts AS(
    SELECT G.Createdate,
           G.Orderid,
           G.OrderStatus,
           G.Customerid,
           G.Restaurantname,
           G.Grp,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Customerid,G.Grp) AS ConsecOrders
    FROM Grps G)
SELECT C.Createdate,
       C.Orderid,
       C.OrderStatus,
       C.Customerid,
       C.Restaurantname
FROM Counts C
WHERE C.ConsecOrders > 1;
```

Note that I get 4 rows in the result set for the above:

```
Createdate Orderid     OrderStatus Customerid  Restaurantname
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
2019-08-12 4853        Accepted    22          Burger King
2019-08-13 5682        NULL        22          Burger King
2019-08-03 1338        Accepted    45          KFC
2019-08-04 3266        Accepted    45          KFC
```

I assume that is expected, as Customer 22 did order from Burger King consecutively (just one of those orders was not accepted). If you only want accepted orders, you *should* easily be able to work out where to add the appropriate `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try `DENSE_RANK()` on that Orders_rank as unlike `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` returns consecutive rank values.

```
SELECT
           o.*
FROM       dbo.Orders       AS o
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                  Customerid
                , Orderid
                , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Rank ORDER BY Customerid) AS Consec
            FROM  dbo.Orders_Rank
            WHERE Rank = 2) AS r ON o.Customerid = r.Customerid
                                    AND o.Orderid = r.Orderid
                                    AND r.Consec = 2
WHERE      o.OrderStatus = 'Accepted'
           AND o.Restaurantname = 'KFC';
```

As always there might be a more elegant way to solve this but something like this should do.